# Multiple tables Mysql JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, inner-join

I have a reference table (main) of products names and a few other tables with alternative names.
At this moment I have 2 tables of alternative names and I display those rows where a FK to the reference table from the table A exist only using

```
SELECT main.id,main.name,tabA.name,tabB.name FROM main INNER JOIN tabA ON tabA.fk=main.id LEFT JOIN tabB ON tabB.fk=main.id ORDER BY main.name
```

How to get all rows where a FK exist from any of the alternative tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT main.id,main.name,tabA.name,tabB.name 
FROM main 
LEFT JOIN tabA ON tabA.fk=main.id 
LEFT JOIN tabB ON tabB.fk=main.id 
ORDER BY main.name
```

Comment: Won't that return all IDs from main whether or not they appear in one of the other tables?

Comment: @octern if this is a concern, use `WHERE tabA.name IS NOT nULL OR tabB.name IS NOT nULL`